# APM Server has still not connected to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, apm

I have installed Elastic search, kibana and logstash (all version 7.5.2)

After this I have installed Kibana(7.5.2) and configured apm-server.yml with output as elasticsearch with xpack monitoring as well. The service apm-server is running fine. I am able to see the APM application in the Kibana `Stack monitoring` page as well.

But when I go to https://kibana_server:5601/app/kibana#/home/tutorial/apm and click on `Check APM Server status`I get as below:

> APM Server has still not connected to Elasticsearch

**apm-server.yml**

```
apm-server:
  host: "lxapm1001:8200"
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://lxecs2001:9200"]
  username: apm_system
  password: "${ES_PWD}"

monitoring.enabled: true
monitoring.elasticsearch:
```

Has anyone faced similar issue. Please advise. Let me know if any additional details are required.

Comment: You probably need to show your APM server configuration

Comment: updated with the configuration file contents

Comment: You might have indentation issues in your configuration file. Make sure that all fields are properly indented, as YAML cares out indentation.

Comment: that was the problem with copy paste. Indentation is fine, the service got started after the configuration change.

Comment: Cool, which change did you make exactly?

Comment: All the lines in the default file was commented. I have changed the above values mentioned in the question. while checking service status(using systemd) it shows running, but the problem is in kibana ui, while i check the service status it shows not connected to elasticsearch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210865/discussion-between-smily-and-val).